# Deciphering AWS CodeDeploy's config and appspec pathing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, cicd, aws-code-deploy-appspec

I have an appspec.yml file sitting in the root of a revision (artifact) I am deploying from CodeCommit:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/app/aws
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: /home/ec2-user/app/aws/update_wheel.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

I changed my `codedeployagent.yml` on my ec2 instance (in order to deal with this issue; changing the `:root_dir:` manually is not an ideal solution, even if it were to have worked):

```
/etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
---
:log_aws_wire: false
:log_dir: '/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/'
:pid_dir: '/opt/codedeploy-agent/state/.pid/'
:program_name: codedeploy-agent
:root_dir: '/home/ec2-user/'
:verbose: false
:wait_between_runs: 1
:proxy_uri:
:max_revisions: 2
```

But I am still getting errors like this:

```
/home/ec2-user/app/aws/update_wheel.sh
Script does not exist at specified location: /home/ec2-user/xxxxxx-cb84-4ef6-966b-xxxxxxxxx/d-xxxxx/deployment-archive/home/ec2-user/app/aws/update_wheel.sh
```

I don't really understand why I am copying `files` to a `destination` and then not expected to be using those files, or why I shouldn't expect those (shell script) files to use their original pathing.  To what `destination` should I be copying the `source` `files` and why can I not get `hooks` to expect the `:root_dir` I set in the codeagent config?

Answer (score 0):

The `location` is always with respect to your [bundle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html):

> . The location in the bundle of the script file for the revision. The location of scripts you specify in the hooks section is **relative to the root of the application revision bundle**.

Since you changed it to `root_dir: '/home/ec2-user/'` all deployments will be stored in that folder. This **requires** the use of `Deployment ID` and `Execution ID` values specific to CodeDeploy.

Thus you should still use only relative paths to the bundle. You can try with:

```
location: run_in_home_folder.sh
```

where `run_in_home_folder.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ec2-user/app/aws && sh ./update_wheel.sh
```